# Replicating GA4 path exploration sankey chart in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I got the below method of replicating the path exploration report from GA4-platform working in Bigquery/Looker Studio, but was wondering if there was a way to change the table into a sankey chart like the one in-platform?

https://gunnargriese.com/posts/bigquery-path-exploration/

Looker studio only takes one value for this type of chart 'weight' - so I'm looking for a way to change the session count to that and make it work across different nodes.